# Displaying the value of a jQuery UI slider and changing color accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-slider

I have a range slider, with a max of 8 and a min of 1.

I have the script already set up to display the value of the range slider in a span. Now i'm trying to change the color and scale whenever the text gets higher.

My code:

```
<span id="currentval">1</span>
            <script>
                if($('#currentval').text() == '1')
                {
                    $('#currentval').css("color","#202a34");
                }
                if($('#currentval').text() == '2')
                {
                    $('#currentval').css("color","#1e3547");
                }
                if($('#currentval').text() == '3')
                {
                    $('#currentval').css("color","#1b405b");
                }
                if($('#currentval').text() == '4')
                {
                    $('#currentval').css("color","#184b6e");
                }
                if($('#currentval').text() == '5')
                {
                    $('#currentval').css("color","#165682");
                }
                if($('#currentval').text() == '6')
                {
                    $('#currentval').css("color","#136095");
                }
                if($('#currentval').text() == '7')
                {
                    $('#currentval').css("color","#116ba9");
                }
                if($('#currentval').text() == '8')
                {
                    $('#currentval').css("color","#0e76bc");
                }
            </script>
```

i guess that best explains what i am trying to do, but i'm unable to do so. I already tried with an onchange event, but i didn't understand it correctly so i threw it away.

I hope someone can help me achieve what im trying to do. Thanks in advance.!

```
    <input type="hidden" name="personen" id="personen">
    <div id="defaultslide"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
            function getPersonen() {
                document.getElementById('personen').value = $('#currentval').text();
            }
```

// if user clicks next, the val will be put in the hidden input

```
            $(function(){
                $('#defaultslide').slider({ 
                    max: 8,
                    min: 1,
                    value: 1,
                    slide: function(e,ui) {
                        $('#currentval').html(ui.value);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: are you using jquery ui slider? if so, please tag it in question. a demo such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would also help.

Comment: Try replacing the if statments with a lookup in an array: `colors=["#f00","#0f0"]; colors[parseInt($("currentval").text())];` Don't forget checking for errors incase the text is not a number.

Comment: @TilwinJoy yes i am using jquery ui slider.
Brainstorm sorry, but i have no idea what you are referring to.

Comment: @Jeroen Hi, the code in question is totally confusing for any future readers. Where is the element with `id` of `currentval`? Where are you calling the function `getPersonen`? why there are multiple `<script>` blocks? Can you put it together and clean it up..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what your looking for

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            function update() {
                var tasks_time = $('#tasks_time').slider('value');

                $("#curr-tasks_time").text(tasks_time);

               if( tasks_time == '1')
                {
                    $('.para').css("color","red");
                }
                 if( tasks_time == '2')
                {
                    $('.para').css("color","blue");
                }



            }

           $( "#tasks_time" ).slider({
                range: "min",
                value: 1,
                min: 1,
                max: 10,
                slide: function() {
                    update();
                }
            });


        });
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/EAaLK/1070/

Comment: that is indeed kind of what i'm looking for.

Comment: It's not the way i'd like to do it, and it's still kind of buggy :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this - You directly can access the value in [slide](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide) callback itself using `ui.value`, and change the color accordingly using an array of colors.

HTML

```
<div id='content'>
  <div id="defaultslide"></div>
  <span id='value'>1</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
var colors = ["red", "dodgerblue","green", "orange","purple"];

$("#defaultslide").slider({
  range: "min",
  value: 1,
  min: 1,
  max: 8,
  slide: function (e, ui) {
    var color = colors[ui.value-1] || "black"
    $('#value').text(ui.value).css('color',color)
  }
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8g7MN/1/)

hope it's clean enough.

Answer (score -2):

Use jQuery.on("change") event.

```
$('#currentval').on("change", function (){
    var myval = $('#currentval').val();
    if(myval=='1') {$('#currentval').css('color','#000000');}
});
```

Every time your slider is moved, the text is changed - somehow. Your code should already be doing that.

That function will assign a trigger on that span of yours, which will see if it has changed and apply required styles.

Edit: apply this to your function of clicking

```
    $('#defaultslide').slider({ 
        max: 8,
        min: 1,
        value: 1,
        slide: function(e,ui) {
            $('#currentval').html(ui.value);
            $('#currentval').trigger("change");
        });
    });
```

Comment: `span` does not have a `change` event